# Group lists by value in it

Tags: python, list, group-by

I'm trying to group group lists by value in it:

```
a = [1,2]
b = [0,1,2]
c = [0,1]
d = [3,4]
e = [3,4,5]
f = [4,5]
g = [2,6]
h = [7,8]
```

So if one value in a list is shared with another list I want to group them into new list. My desired output in my case:

```
out = ([a,b,c,g],[d,e,f],[h])
```

To accomplish this, I have attempted the following:

```
lists = IN[0] 
values = IN[1] 
out = [] 
out1=[] 
def check(valeur , lists): 
    if valeur in lists: 
        result = True 
    else: 
        result = False 
    return result 

for list in lists: 
    out1=[] 
    for i in values: 
        out1.append(check(i,list)) 
    out.append(out1) 
OUT = out
```

My poor brain is dying...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to check for each value (from 0 to 8) if its in each list. But after this I don't know what to do with this information

Comment: Can you please add the code you used to the question? Also, how do you handle if a list has values that would appear in multiple sets?

Comment: ```lists = IN[0]
values = IN[1]
out = []
out1=[]

def check(valeur , lists):
 if valeur in lists:
  result = True
 else:
  result = False
 return result
 
for list in lists:
 out1=[]
 for i in values:
  out1.append(check(i,list))
 out.append(out1)
OUT = out
```

I'm not an expert so my code might not be in the perfect way :D
and I code in IronPython in a software add-on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by graph [Union-Find algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)

Nodes of the graph are the lists:

```
a = [1,2]
b = [0,1,2]
c = [0,1]
d = [3,4]
e = [3,4,5]
f = [4,5]
g = [2,6]
h = [7,8]
```

Nodes are connected if they have an element in common (i.e. the two lists intersect).

**Optimized Union-Find Code**

```
def find(data, i):
 " finds parent of i optimized so O(log(n)) operation "
  if i != data[i]:
      data[i] = find(data, data[i])
  return data[i]

# A function that does union of two sets of x and y 
# (uses union by rank) 
def union(data, rank, x, y): 
  xroot = find(data, x) 
  yroot = find(data, y) 

  # Attach smaller rank tree under root of  
  # high rank tree (Union by Rank) 
  if rank[xroot] < rank[yroot]: 
      data[xroot] = yroot 
  elif rank[xroot] > rank[yroot]: 
      data[yroot] = xroot 

  # If ranks are same, then make one as root  
  # and increment its rank by one 
  else : 
      data[yroot] = xroot 
      rank[xroot] += 1
```

**Usage**

```
# Aggregate lists
lst = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]
n = len(lst)
# Elements of lists as node vertices (0, 1, 2, etc.)
# With: 0 -> a, 1 -> b, 2 -> c, 3 -> d, etc. of our sublists
data = [i for i in range(n)]  # list of vertices
# initialize ranks
rank = [0]*n

# Find pairs of vertices with connections (create generator)
connections = ((i, j) for i in range(n) for j in range(i+1, n) if len(set(lst[i]).intersection(lst[j])) > 0)

# Create union of all connections
for i, j in connections:
  union(data, rank, i, j)

# Aggrgate all connected components (i.e. vertices with the same parent)
d = {}
for i in range(n):
  # find(data, i) => parent of i
  # Append all vertices with the same parent into the same list
  d.setdefault(find(data, i), []).append(lst[i])

print(*d.values(), sep = '\n')
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1], [2, 6]]
[[3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5]]
[[7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easily viewed as a graph problem. Each list is a node, two nodes have an edge between them if they share any common elements, and you want the connected components of the graph, i.e. each set of nodes where there is a path between any two nodes. Using the popular graph library networkx:

```py
import networkx
from itertools import combinations
from pprint import pprint

a = [1,2]
b = [0,1,2]
c = [0,1]
d = [3,4]
e = [3,4,5]
f = [4,5]
g = [2,6]
h = [7,8]

nodes = list(map(frozenset, [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]))

G = networkx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)

for n1, n2 in combinations(nodes, 2):
    if n1.intersection(n2):
        G.add_edge(n1, n2)

pprint(list(networkx.connected_components(G)))
```

Demo here: https://repl.it/repls/OutrageousDisfiguredCopyright

Comment: I get a `ModuleNotFound` Error when trying your demo.

Comment: @Jan You most likely need to `pip install networkx`.